# Python regex replace only subgroup

Tags: python, regex

I would like to change all words that occur after from/on to 1_ only that occurs after from or on

input

```
with crossroad
from crossroad
(on pike)
```

expected output

```
with crossroad
from (1_crossroad)
(on (1_pike))
```

Code I tried :

```
rgxsubtable = re.compile(r"(?:from|on)[\s]+([\w\d.\"]+)",re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE) # find the occurance to change
tlist = set(rgxsubtable.findall(input))

for item in tlist:
    input = re.sub(r"(?!\B\w){0}(?<!\w\B)".format(re.escape(item)),"(1_{0})".format(item),input )
```

This would replace both crossroads instead of only crossroad after "from" which I know. But I don't know how to selectively replace the word after from/on only

output obtained

```
with (1_crossroad)
from (1_crossroad)
(on (1_pike))
```

Comment: Please check if https://ideone.com/GLNBfn solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "with crossroad\nfrom crossroad\n(on pike)"
rgxsubtable = re.compile(r"\b((?:from|on)\s+)([\w.\"]+)", re.IGNORECASE) # find the occurance to change
print( rgxsubtable.sub(r"\1(1_\2)", text) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GLNBfn) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J14iSq/1).

**NOTE**: If the strings after `from` and `on` are just non-whitespace text chunks, replace `[\w.\"]+` with `\S+`.

Also, pay attention to the replacement pattern: it is defined with a raw string literal, `r"..."`, so as to avoid overescaping.

*Pattern details*

- `\b` - a word boundary to make sure we match whole words
- `((?:from|on)\s+)`  - Group 1 (`\1`): `from` or `on` and then one or more whitespaces
- `([\w.\"]+)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more word, `.` or `"` chars.
- `\S+` - matches one or more chars other than whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Wictor for the answer. Is it possible to further playaround with the captured group. For example if capture group2 gives me crossroad, I would like to take last 3 characters or if capture group 2 gives me cross-road, and I want to use split function to take just road.

Comment: @Leo See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/qhLKoB), it might give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this would be the following:

```py
import re
from typing import List

string = """with crossroad
from crossroad
(on pike)"""

exclusion_list: List[str] = ["\n", "\\)"]
string = re.sub(fr"from ([^{''.join(exclusion_list)}]*)", r"from (1_\g<1>)", string)
string = re.sub(fr"on ([^{''.join(exclusion_list)}]*)", r"on (1_\g<1>)", string)
print(string)
```

Output:

```
with crossroad  
from (1_crossroad)  
(on (1_pike))
```

This assumes there is a `\n` character between lines, to capture the whole expression after the keyword. In this code, each `re.sub` call will replace every occurrences of one case, either `from XXX` or `on XXX`.
Additionally, pay attention this works in this case, but might break in other cases, for instance if you had `[on pike]`, the resulting line would be `[on (pike])`. You might want to add some characters to the exclusion list.
The exclusion list is then added to the pattern by using a formatted (`f`) raw (`r`) string. This will capture everything on the line until one of the excluded characters are present.
This has one major consequence, the characters in the exclusion list need to be properly escaped to achieve your goal. For instance, if you wanted to capture only the first word after `from` and `on`, you would want to add the space as an excluded character. For this, the pattern itself would need `\s` to be added, thus we would need to add `\\s` in the list (we need to double escape in order for a single escape to be present in the pattern).
Finally, we are here using the same exclusion list for both cases, you obviously can use two different lists.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a positive look behind to match `from` and `on` without including them in the answer.

This Regex `(?<=(from|on) )([^\s]+)`, will match any string after `from` and `on` such that you can replace it.

You can see it in action [here](https://regexr.com/73vb3)

Comment: Your pattern is invalid in Python `re`, see https://regex101.com/r/KVhaEm/1

Comment: TIL Regex can be very different between languages